Ishta Devta - a must?
Namaskar,
Do we need to have an Ishta Devta?
This concept is very new to me, and as long as I remember I have offered prayers to multiple deities.
Appreciate your take on this.
Thanks.

Srimad Mahabhagavata (Shakti Pithanka) Purana, 81.11-14.:

उपायो विद्यते नान्यः सत्यं सत्यं कलौ युगे।
शम्भोराराधनात्स्वल्पसाधनान्मुनिसत्तम ।।
शम्भोराराधनसमं नास्ति कर्म कलौ युगे।
शाक्तो वा वैष्णवः शेवः पूर्वं सम्पूज्य श‌ङ्करम् ।।
पश्चात्प्रपूजयेत्स्वेष्टदेवतां भक्तिभावतः ।
It is the ultimate truth that In Kaliyuga, there is no other solution except worshiping Shiva because through this one gets freedom from the bondage of evil with little bit of spiritual practices. That is because, by worshiping Lord Shiva, a person easily achieves success in Kaliyuga. In Kaliyuga, there is no action equal to the worship of Shambhu. Whether one is a Shakta, Vaishnava or Shaiva, he should first worship Lord Shankara. After this, one should worship one's Ishta Deva with devotion.

I hope this helps. Prd..

Sure, but I have only the sanskrit verses and no transliteration. So, i am updating with the sanskrit verses only. I hope this helps you. Prd..

Actually, this is kinda, a Khila Purana of Devi Bhagwatam. Like Harivamsha is of Mahabharata. Or like an expansion of it like Vayu Purana is an expansion of Shiva Purana. It basically talks about Shiva-Shakti and Shaktipeeths, etc.. And you are welcome man.

@SriShivaCharañamDāsaVishñu Thank-you! Your post convinced me to hold on to Lord Shiva, but your statement did mention that one must worship Ishta Devta after praying to Lord Shiva. Does it mean, it's would be best to know our Ishta Devta?

Your Ishta Deva is that form of lord in which you are initiated. Like different sampradayas have different ishta deva.

Ishta Devta is the one who you resonate more. This reverberation is what Yoga Sutras call Bhavana (The Science of Yoga IK Taimni Chap1-3). Bhavana means that with which your emotions and energies Aline. The proces that best suits your need as per your question is the process of Panchayatanam. Pancha means 5, they are Ganesha, Vishnu, Devi, Shiva and Surya. The Kula devata goes in the center, if one doesn't know their Kula then their Istha goes in the center. The upacharas (offerings) start with the surrounding 4 devatas and finally to the one in the center. If one tends to give more preference to Istha then one can spend more time on Upacharas for that Deity. Panchayatana culture was attributed to Adi Shankara to break the barriers between various sects. But many scholars think that Panchayatana tradition existed before Adi Shankara. Mahamundeshwari temples attributed as one of the oldest in Bihar is considered to have Panchayatana. Following is a link to understand the placement of Divinities in a Panchayatana.
Source link for Panchayatana structure
